# Getting user id/token from Google Workspace calendar add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am in the process of creating a Google Workspace calendar add-on for conferencing. The Appscript for the add-on itself has required oauth scopes to access calendar events and is associated to a project in Google Cloud Platform - but when I go to create the create the conference in my API I am getting the event id, but no other information about the user creating it.

Is there something I need to change/adjust in my Appscript or GCP project so when the add-on is initially authorized that I can get the user info posted to my API or can pull that information when I go to create the conference when the event is created?

I'm using the add-on example here: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample

Cheers

Comment: Getting user info is not always guarantee.  As Google explains it `it depends upon a complex set of rules` so even in the best of cases  you will have to learn how to deal with no having access to them

Comment: How do I associate a calendar event to a user then? The sample code tries to fetch the calendar event like: `calendarEvent = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);` and with just an eventId/calendarId how can I associate that to a user in my system?

Comment: That may require a work around of your own.